# In WebFlux Reactive controller onErrorResume don't work

Tags: spring-webflux

WebFlux
In a GET controller I need to check connectivity to mongo db to verify liveness from Kubernates point of view, but when I disconnect the db, the code doesn't enter in onErrorResume. Why? A possible solution?

```
@RequestMapping("/liveness-for-kubernates/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> livenessForKubernates(@PathVariable @NotBlank String id) {
    return Mono.just(id)
            .map(golamService::findById)
            .map(result -> new ResponseEntity<String>("UP", HttpStatus.OK))
            .onErrorResume(
                    throwable -> Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<String>("DOWN", HttpStatus.OK)));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findById` is an asynchronous, non-blocking operation resulting in a `Mono` publisher. Thus, you should wrap it into a `flatmap` instead of `map`:

```java
return Mono.just(id)
            .flatmap(golamService::findById)
            .map(result -> new ResponseEntity<String>("UP", HttpStatus.OK))
            .onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<String>("DOWN", HttpStatus.OK)));
```

`map` is for synchronous, non-blocking, 1-to-1 transformations.

Comment: Thanks a lot @IkatiForis ! I haven't seen it ! :)